# Showing the group in $\Bbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following problem I am confused about:

Let $x,y\in \Bbb R, x\ast y=xy+x+y$

Is $\Bbb R$ a group? I wrote $(x\ast y)\ast z= x\ast (y\ast z)$, then calculated it, associativity did not hold. Is this true?

My mistake apparently is that I wrote $xy\ast z+ x\ast z+ y\ast z$.

Secondly, I am asked to prove that $\Bbb R \setminus \{-1\}$ is a group. I have no idea how to do this. A methodological answer would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The so called "star multiplication" or "circle multiplication" is associative - please check your calculations.

Comment: Once you have associativity you shouldn't have trouble proving it's a group if you exclude $-1$. The identity is a very distinguished real number that you could guess, and the inverse is obtained by solving a linear equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operation *is* associative:

$$\begin{align*}
(x*y)*z&=(xy+x+y)*z\\
&=(xy+x+y)z+(xy+x+y)+z\\
&=\color{red}{xyz}+\color{red}{xz}+yz+\color{red}{xy}+x+y+z\\
&=\color{red}{x(yz+y+z)}+x+(yz+y+z)\\
&=x*(yz+y+z)\\
&=x*(y*z)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: My mistake is, I wrote it as $xy\ast z+ x\ast z+ y\ast z$ after the first line

Comment: Can you please help me with the second part too?

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton: What part of the second part are you having trouble with? Finding an identity? For that you want $e$ such that $x*e=x$, or $xe+x+e=x$; just solve that for $e$.

Comment: @BrianMScott I am asked to prove that $\Bbb R \setminus \{-1\}$ is a group. I have problem with that too

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton: I understand the question; I’m asking what part of proving that it’s a group is causing you trouble. Do you know what you have to check? That’s just a matter of knowing the definition of a group.

Comment: I know the definitions I need to check but I do not understand why is $-1$ excluded?

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton: You’ll find out when you work out what the inverse of an arbitrary element is: $-1$ would not have an inverse, so we have to exclude it.

Comment: I worked out the identity to be $-1$. Now I tried to find $x^{-1}=\frac{1}{x\ast y}$ and then I divide by $0$, so the element has no inverse

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton: The identity can’t be $-1$: that’s not even in the set. When you solve $xe+x+e=x$ for $e$, you first get $xe+e=0$, then $(x+1)e=0$. Since $x$ can’t be $-1$ and *can* be any other real number, this implies that $e$ must be $0$. Check: $x*0=x\cdot 0+x+0=x$, and $0*x=0\cdot x+0+x=x$. Now $x^{-1}$ must satisfy $x*x^{-1}=0$, or $x\cdot x^{-1}+x+x^{-1}=0$. Solve this for $x^{-1}$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: @IdiotfromPrinceton: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 3):

One way to check that a given algebraic structure is a group, while avoiding checking of all the axioms separately, is to find an isomorphism with a group.

In particular, your group is isomorphic with $({\bf R}^*,\cdot)$. The isomorphism is somewhat self-evident, and it is not hard to check that it is indeed an isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

$(x*y)*z$=$(xy+x+y)*z$=$(xy+x+y)z+xy+x+y+z$=$xyz+xz+yz+xy+x+y+z$.

$x*(y*z)$=$x*(yz+y+z)$=$x(yz+y+z)+x+yz+y+z)$=$xyz+xy+xz+yz+x+y+z$

it is associative

Answer (score 0):

To find an identity element: If $x*y=x$ for all $x,$ then $x y+x+y=x$ for all $x\ne -1.$ Once you find out which number $y$ is the $*$-identity, then to find the $*$-inverse of any $x\ne -1,$ you need to solve $y=x*z=x z+x+z$ for $z.$

Comment: Try this one;  In a ring R, for which we do not assume a left- or right- multiplicative identity, an LQI (Left Quasi-Inverse) for $x$ is any $y$ such that $y+x- yx=0.$ If there is exactly one member of $R$ that does not have an LQI then $ R$ is a division ring with unit. (i.e., Multiplication in $R\backslash \{0\}$ is a group.)